# Simplify or rules don't work with square roots

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am trying to simplify a complicated expression and neither `Simplify` nor rules are working for me.

Here is a very basic example of what I am trying to do:

[image]

Simplify doesn't do any simplification and rules somehow don't apply for the denominator.

How can I get Mathematica to simplify the expression to `Sin[z]/z`?

---

My Mathematica input:

```
Simplify[Sin[Sqrt[x + y]]/Sqrt[x + y], Sqrt[x + y] == z]

Sin[Sqrt[x + y]]/Sqrt[x + y] /. {Sqrt[x + y] -> z}
```

Comment: Try `FullForm[Sqrt[x+z]]` and `FullForm[1/Sqrt[x+z]]`.  These show the actual expressions you are trying to transform, not the typeset version that you see in the Front End.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29219/4999

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Hey Michael, thank you for that link! Is there a way to also paste Mathematica's output? I wanted to show what I tried together with the output to show how my approach was not working..

Comment: You can paste output in the same was as input.  Note that square-roots will be formatted as `Sqrt[..]`, so sometimes I paste an image of the output when I want to show the typeset form.  The principal point of the link is that making input copy-pasteable is a convenience to others that invites their help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way:

```
Sin[Sqrt[x + y]]/Sqrt[x + y] /. (x + y)^(r_) :> z^(2 r)
(*  Sin[z]/z  *)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simplify using Surd[ ,2] instead of Sqrt

```
Sin[Surd[x + y, 2]]/Surd[x + y, 2] /. Surd[x + y, 2] -> z
Sin[z]/z
```

Comment: Note that `Surd[z, 2]` is equivalent to `Sqrt[z]` only if `z` is nonnegative real.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to help it a little

```
ClearAll[x, y];
expr = Sin[Sqrt[x + y]]/Sqrt[x + y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
expr /. {1/Sqrt[x + y] -> 1/z, Sqrt[x + y] -> z}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1. Nice to have an assumption-free alternative. I often do it this way, because copy-paste-edit makes it easy to type both rules.

Answer (score 3):

Yet an other way:

```
sol = First@Solve[Sqrt[x + y] == z, x]

      (*   {x -> -y + z^2}   *)

Sin[Sqrt[x + y]]/Sqrt[x + y] /. sol // 
    PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> z > 0] &
```

Or

```
Sin[Sqrt[x + y]]/Sqrt[x + y] /. sol // 
     Simplify[#, Assumptions -> z > 0] &

(*   Sin[z]/z   *)
```

Comment: In an expression that had other occurrences of `x`, this would produce additional substitutions that the OP might well not want.

Answer (score 3):

Since I had a similar problem same problem some time ago I'd like to expand on the other answers why mathematica does not simplify the expressions with the initial second attempt. `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) does not hold its arguments. That means both arguments will be evaluated before any replacements are performed.

The left hand side of `/.` after evaluation can be found with

```
Sin[Sqrt[x + y]]/Sqrt[x + y] // FullForm
```

which gives

```
Times[Power[Plus[x,y],Rational[-1,2]],Sin[Power[Plus[x,y],Rational[1,2]]]]
```

Note the `-1` which represents the inverse of the square root. The `FullForm` of the pattern after evaluation is.

```
Power[Plus[x,y],Rational[1,2]]
```

The pattern is clearly different from the expression in the pattern and hence mathematica will (correctly) not replace it.

Multiple suggestions have already been given how to obtain the desired result. I'd like to give two more suggestions.

### Unevaluated

One could wrap both sides in `Unevaluated` which will shield them from evaluation before replacement is performed.

```
Unevaluated[Sin[Sqrt[x+y]]/Sqrt[x+y]]/.Unevaluated[{Sqrt[x + y] -> z}]
```

this gives the desired result

```
Sin[z]/z
```

To see the difference to the first attempt use `FullForm` on the `Uneavlated` expression.

### Pattern matching

My second attempt would be to improve on the pattern matching. Inspect that according to the output of the first equation the square root can also be written as `Power[Plus[x, y], Rational[n_, 2]]` with `n_` replaced by either `-1` or `1`.

We will now use a slightly different right hand side of `/.` which contains the pattern `n_` to match both expressions on the evaluated left hand side

```
Sin[Sqrt[x+y]]/Sqrt[x+y] /. Power[Plus[x,y],Rational[n_,2]] :> Power[z,n]
```

which again gives the desired output `Sin[z]/z`.

In conclusion pattern matching and non-standard evaluation can be very helpful features of mathematica. Especially non-standard evaluation is often essential to understand results which look quirky at first glance.

Answer (score 2):

If your ultimate aim is to simplify the equation, you can use `OptimizeExpression` from `Experimental`: it works in more general cases as well:

```
$Context = "Compile`";(*improve formatting for copy*)
Experimental`OptimizeExpression[Sin[x + y]/Sqrt[x + y]]
```

gives

> ```
> Experimental`OptimizedExpression[Block[{$1}, 
>   $1 = x + y;  
>   Sin[$1]/Sqrt[$1]
> ]]
> ```